# Finding Intersection given probabilities

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

If I have events $A$ and $B$ where $P(A) = 0.20$ and $P(B) = 0.13$. Can we find the $P (A \cap B)$ and show that events are independent?

[image]

Comment: What you mean, for example, under $A = 0.20$?

Comment: No we cannot. I can keep moving the circles and keep changing the area of intersection.

Comment: The other way round, if we know they are independent then yes.

Comment: @zkutch: Probability of event 'A'.

Comment: @MathLover believe it or not, I think that your (elegant) first comment should be transplanted to a 2 sentence *answer*.

Comment: @MathLover: What does keep moving circles means?

Comment: I mean can I not take circle A and B farther or closer changing the area of their intersection? There has to be more info available to fix the area of the intersection, for example, you could say both events are independent.

Comment: @user2661923 thank you for your comment.

Comment: @MathLover: I see. So, if my circles don't touch each other at all. Then I suppose intersection is zero, but with just probabilities you don't know size of circles.

Comment: Yes that is correct because area of individual circles remain the same (given probabilities of $A$ and $B$ )and intersection keeps changing. We have no other information to bind the area of intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing only probabilities $P(A)=0.20$ and $P(B)=0.13$ it is impossible to unambiguously define probability for $P(A \cap B)$, which can have any value from $[0,0.13]$, so is not possible to determine independence.

Also let me point out that for the given probabilities for $A,B$, if the intersection is empty $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $A,B$ are, of course, dependent.

Comment: Does $A \cap B=∅$ means mutually exclusive i.e. circles don't touch each other?

Comment: Yes, in words when $A \cap B = \emptyset$ we called them mutually exclusive. So, we can say, that if mutually exclusive events have non zero probabilities, then they are necessarily dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The independence of two events $A$ and $B$ can be characterized by their joint probability. Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if their joint probability of $A\cap B $ equals the product of their individual probabilities.

$P(A\cap B)=P(A).P(B)$ implies $P(A \lvert B)= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=P(A)$

Comment: That means my $P (A \cap B)$ is `0.20 x 0.13 = 0.026`?

Comment: @user963241 that is true iff A and B are independent